# SuiteScript 2.0 Transaction Saved Search Filter

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have created a saved search for transaction in netsuite and with suitescript 2.0 I am showing saved search data in my application. In application user can apply filter on any fields [(please see the attached screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBck1.png). For example user select "Aug 2011" for posting period, only transactions of Aug 2011 should be loaded. This works fine if I create a filter with internalid of "Aug 2011", but on UI I dont have internal id.

sample code:

```
/*
 here is my required module
*/

function getTransactionData(datain)
{
  try
  {

       var objSearch = search.load
                    ({
                        id: datain.savedsearchid
                    });
          /***** Work *****/
          objSearch.filters.push(search.createFilter({ name: "postingperiod",  operator: "ANYOF", values: "1" })); //here 1 is internalid of periodname "Aug 2011"

          /***** Not Work (SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_JOIN) *****/
          //objSearch.filters.push(search.createFilter({ name: "postingperiod", join: "accountingperiod",  operator: "ANYOF", values: "Aug 2011" }));

           objSearch.run();
  }
  catch(ex)
  {
      log.error("getTransactionData",  ex);
      throw ex;
  }
}
```

I tried with join but seeing "SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_JOIN" error from Netsuite.

Can any one please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I edited your code to a more simplified one to understand better.
If you get the gist of how it works, you can edit/customize the way you want.

I assume there is join 'accountingperiod' option available for 'postingperiod' and this works perfectly in your saved search you created in netsuite without using suitescript.

```
/*
 here is my required module
*/

function getTransactionData(datain) {
    try {

        var objSearch = search.load({
            id: datain.savedsearchid
        });
        var defaultFilters = objSearch.filters;
        var customFilters = [];

        //Adding filter
        customFilters = ['postingperiod', 'ANYOF', '1'];
        defaultFilters.push(customFilters);
        customFilters = undefined;
        customFilters = [];



        //Adding filter
        /*
        customFilters = ['postingperiod.accountingperiod', 'ANYOF', 'Aug 2011'];
        defaultFilters.push(customFilters);
        */

        objSearch.filters = defaultFilters;

        var objSearch_run = objSearch.run().getRange({
            start: 0,
            end: 10
        });

    } catch (ex) {
        log.error("getTransactionData", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

If you want to know how filters is stored in saved search you created in netsuite, you can use the script debugger.
The following code is suitescript 1.0

```
//Load Saved Search
get();

function get() {
    var search = nlapiLoadSearch('transaction', ' ENTER SAVED SEARCH ID HERE ');
    log.debug('search',search);
    var searchFilters = search.getFilterExpression();
    log.debug('searchFilters',searchFilters);

    return search;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Manu, here "1" is an internalid of periodname "Aug 2011" and that internalid I dont know in my wpf application, that why I wanted to filter transactions based on periodname not based on internalid

Answer (score 0):

I assume your application is a Suitelet?  If so, you need to do a select field type of your record.  So probably of 'posting periods'.  This will show your periods in a drop down.

When the user selects it, have a client side script auto refresh the data and load your saved search.

Alternatively, you can load all the data and do the filtering client side DOM filtering.  Really need a bit more information about your "application".

Comment: my application is .net wpf application, not suitelet.

Comment: Have you tried changing the filter to: objSearch.filters.push(search.createFilter({ name: "postingperiod", join: "accountingperiod",  operator: "ANYOF", values: "1" }));

Comment: here "1" is an internalid of periodname "Aug 2011" and that internalid I dont know in my wpf application, that why I wanted to filter transactions based on periodname not based on internalid

Comment: You may need to do two searches.  First do a search of all posting periods and get the internal id and names.  Then do a filter/match on the internalid you require?

Comment: it seems you are right, I will have to make two search